# How to Scroll an iFrame using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, scroll

I have several iFrames that load an external webpage, although only 1 appears at a time, hence all have the id="iFrame" I want to add to buttons (not the scrollbar) so the user can scroll down or up by pressing them, and I am trying to do this using javascript but so far I've been unsuccessful, I've read some posts here and tried [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192228/scrolling-an-iframe-with-javascript) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656665/using-javascript-to-scroll-iframe-up-and-down) but so far no luck. I have also tried:

```
var newFrame = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
if(typeof newFrame !== 'undefined'){
    newFrame.contentWindow.scrollBy(0,250);
```

and

```
var myframe = document.getElementById(window.frameElement[0].id);
myframe.window.scrollBy(0,50);
```

nothing has worked out so far, could anyone let me know what am I missing or doing wrong? thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use the following (untested, but should work):

```
function scrollIFrame(name, x, y)
{
    var frame = document.getElementById(name);        
    frame.contentWindow.scrollTo(x, y);         
}
```

So, you would use:

```
scrollIFrame('iframe', 0, 250);
```

Comment: Bugger, that was silly of me, fixed, but not convinced it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var iFrames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var i = 0; i < iFrames.length; i++) {
    //+= for -= depending on direction
    //scrollLeft for horizontal, scrollTop for vertical
    //iFrames[i].contentWindow.scrollTop += 10;
    iFrames[i].contentWindow.scrollTop -= 10;
}
```

`scrollBy` and `scrollTo` should work just the same.  The important thing here is that `getElementsByTagName` returns an array.  If you run this `newFrame.contentWindow.scrollBy(0,250);` you are not scrolling the iframe, but trying to scroll the array.  Instead, you would have to run this:  `newFrame[0].contentWindow.scrollBy(0,250);`