# jquery iframe scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe in my page and i want to create a button that when i press it the page in the iframe scrolls down...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

```
  $("#scrolldownbut").click(function()
  { 
      var q=$("#theframe").scrollTop();

      q=q+100;
      $("#theframe").scrollTop(q);

      return false;  
  });
```

This code works fore me. The frame's id and name is `theframe` and the `scrollbut` is a div to scroll down the frame. Notice: the frames width and height must not be in percentage (thats what i wanted to do) because in percentage it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this article answers it better than I ever would - http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Let me elaborate:

I've used flesler's library before for the same purpose(scrolling an iFrame inside a facebook application, same deal more or less) and it's honestly beautiful. The linked article explains several detailed situations in how you'd use scrollTo, and it works nicely.

Comment: I checked it quickly.Thank you. Do i have to download a plygin?

Comment: I would also appreciate it if you could give me an example... i didnt see anything in the link you sent me! Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be useful if you provide your code for scrolling the iframe since the example page doesn't includes an example to scroll an iframe and it seems not to work the standard way with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll an iFrame using Javascript with the scrollTo and scrollBy methods. This has been discussed here before, and the answer there has a simple example:

[How to Scroll an iFrame using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365567/how-to-scroll-an-iframe-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

To use flesler, you can do

```
<div id="pane-target" class="pane">
  <iframe style="width:1000px; height:1000px" src="MyInformation.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: <div id="left">&laquo;</div> <div id="right">&raquo;</div>
  <div id="block"><iframe src="http://www.ipolistonkosmo.gr  /theater.php?all=yes" id="cinframe" name="cinframe"   frameborder="no"   scrolling="auto" ></iframe></div>
<script>
//$("#cinframe")._scrollable();
$("#right").click(function(){
 
  $("#block cinframe").scrollTo( '+=340px', { axis:'y' } );
});

  $("#left").click(function(){
    $("#block cinframe").scrollTo( '-=340px', { axis:'y' } );
  });

  </script>

Comment: scroll up and see the answer :) its the answer #4 !!

Comment: Ah - I see now it was your own comment. Thanks