# Tricky iframe view

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is somewhat of an odd question but I'm wanting to have a circle (or some shape) bounce around an iframe and only expose the inside of the circle.

[image: Example:]

So how can I do this while

- Making this no bigger than the circle (meaning the iframe doesn't take up space)
- Appearing to 'bounce around' a larger canvas?

**Got the scroll to work with this code. Now I just have to make a bounce function!**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('iframe').contents().find("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 250 }, { duration: 'medium', easing: 'swing' });
})
```

*Thanks to http://forum.jquery.com/topic/adjust-the-scroll-position-of-an-iframe*

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/accw5/4/)

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/accw5/1/ I'm clueless on how to bounce around the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You will have some cross domain issues if you are framing up stuff from another domain. Heres a post how to scroll a iframe that is not in your domain:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1656930/2033671

to bounce you can set the position of the item to absolute and just move its top & left css property.

## html

```
<div id="google">
    <iframe width="800" height="600" src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/" scrolling="no" />
</div>
```

## css

```
#google {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius:20%;
left:0px;
top:0px;
position:absolute;
}
```

## js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$frame = $('#google');
$frame.scrollTop(0).scrollLeft(0);
 $frame.animate({
    left: '+=100',
    top: '+=100'
}, {
    duration: 4000,
    step: function () {
        $frame.scrollLeft($frame.scrollLeft() + 1);
        $frame.scrollTop($frame.scrollTop() + 1);
    }
});
return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/accw5/5/

It's not bouncing but it is a start.

Comment: Thanks. The bounce is kind of tricky, I think I'll just generate random numbers based on dimensions of the iframe content and have it update every 10 seconds or so. Nice work getting `scrollTop` to work, I tried $('iframe') but it didn't work.