# jquery, how to Scroll iFrame with source from outside site?

Tags: jquery, iframe, scroll, src

I am trying to have an ***iframe*** on my site that will **load a site from the internet** **and** automatically perform a **scroll** down scroll **(animate)**.

It **works** if I have as a src a **simple page (local)** with some content but when i change the *src* to and external source, it does not longer works.

the *'ticks'* variable don't get incremented, loos like it loses the scope, **what is going on**?

- "**DOES NOT WORK**: *iframe id="frame" src="http://www.thePage.com" scrolling="yes" /*"
- **WORKS**: iframe height="100%" id="frame" src="./mypage2.html" scrolling="yes"/*

Here is an example:

```
<html>
     <head>
        <title></title>
      </head>

    <body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">

    <iframe height="100%" id="frame" src="http://plugins.jquery.com" scrolling="yes"  ></iframe>

</body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

   var ticks = 1;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        self.setInterval("scrolldown1("+(ticks+1)+")",5000);
    });


    function scrolldown1(tick) {
        alert("scrolldown" +  ticks);
        $("#frame").contents().scrollTop(ticks*100);
        ticks = ticks + 2;
    }


    </script>

</html>
```

Thanks for your time, I cannot understand why it does not scroll when I *src* and external site!

Answer (score 2):

Because of the same-origin policy, it's not really possible.

One way to solve it is to load the entire third party website in a very long `iframe`, put that `iframe` in a `div` with `overflow: auto` and then scroll the `div` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please post a simple example? I could not get it working with the iframe on the DIV. Thanks again

Comment: I found a similar question with this solution as the accepted answer. Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656665/using-javascript-to-scroll-iframe-up-and-down